# Do we have to use Websocket Sampler for Signalr. Is it an obligation or an advice in JMeter?

Tags: websocket, jmeter, signalr

i am doing performance tests of rest api web service. the application uses signalr library. i have a problem with signalr. there are four requests for signalr protocol. the others are login issues.

signalr/negotiate

signalr/connect

signalr/start

signalr/abort

i have done correlation for connection token and it works for **signalr/start**.

but **signalr/connect** has no response and the error returns such as :

*Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketTimeoutException*

i looked the differences from browser and jmeter by using wireshark and didnt see any major differences.

i tried a lot of things but still problem is going on.

i am wondering Web Socket Sampler is an obligation? Also i have tried this sampler. but probably i couldnt manage it, it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

In the majority of cases given you send the same request you should get the same response so if the request succeeds in browser and doesn't in JMeter most probably there are differences (protocol, methods, URL, headers, body, etc.)

We cannot help without seeing the successful and failed request details so I can only give you the following piece of advice: if you don't see "major differences" pay attention to the "minor" ones as well.

With regards to WebSocket Sampler - again we don't know, as per [SignalR Transport Protocols documentation](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/master/specs/TransportProtocols.md#transport-protocols)

> This document describes the protocols used by the three ASP.NET Endpoint Transports: WebSockets, Server-Sent Events and Long Polling

Depending on your application implementation you will have either one or any combination of them, most probably it will be WebSockets, but I cannot guarantee it 100% without seeing the network traffic dump between your browser and your system under test. WebSocket Samplers are pretty well described in the [official documentation](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/) and 3rd-party articles like [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide)

Comment: thank you. in wireshark i noticed some of requests that jmeter sends which are not on request list. these are not related with signalr issue directly. i am going to ask this in an other question